# Why $\gcd \{ {\rm ord}_p(q)\colon q\mid p-1 \}$ likes to be large?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

For a prime $p$, let $F_p$ denote the greatest common divisor of the orders modulo $p$ of all prime divisors of $p-1$:
  $$ F_p = \gcd \{ {\rm ord}_p(q)\colon q\mid p-1 \}; $$
thus, for instance, $F_3=2$, $F_5=4$, $F_7=3$, and $F_p$ is a divisor of $p-1$ for all $p$.

There exist primes $p$ with $F_p=1$, the smallest of them being $31$, $307$, and $601$. The strange thing is, there are rather few such primes; say, out of the 78,497 odd primes up to $10^6$, there are only 86 primes $p$ with $F_p=1$. Is there any explanation to this phenomenon?

Generally, $F_p$ tends to be large. The following histogram presents the "density function" of the quantity $\log F_p/\log p$, for all primes $p<10^6$:

$\hskip 1in$ [image: Density Distribution] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://math.haifa.ac.il/~seva/MathOverflow/F-Histo.jpg)

As the histogram shows, there are almost no primes $p$ with $F_p<p^{1/4}$, and for the vast majority of primes we actually have $F_p>\sqrt p$. This can also be read from the "cumulative distribution function":

$\hskip 1in$ [image: Cumulative Distribution] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://math.haifa.ac.il/~seva/MathOverflow/F-Plot.jpg)

Both plots behave rather enigmatically, but my major question is:

> $\hskip 1in$ Why $F_p$ is "normally" that large? Why $F_p=1$ holds that rarely?

In case it matters, I am actually interested in the situation where $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ and $p-1$ is $\sqrt p$-smooth.

Comment: If $q|(p-1)$ and $a$ is coprime to $p$ then $q|\text{ord}_p(a)$ unless $a$ is a $q$-th power.  Thus with probability $1-1/q$ we know that $q|\text{ord}_p(a)$.  Use this idea with say the largest prime factor of $p-1$. Since $p-1$ has about $\log\log p$ prime factors, it is very likely that all of them are not $q$-th powers, and then $q$ will divide your gcd.  Maybe this can be made rigorous with some work.

Comment: Thanks, Lucia, your remark is quite insightful (though it seems difficult to *prove* anything along these lines).

Comment: Yes, it does seem difficult to prove anything.  But your question only asked for explanations, not proofs! The heuristic above also suggests that in fact one should expect $F_p$ to be of size $p^{1-\epsilon}$ almost always.

Comment: If anyone is interested, here is a histogram of $F_p/p$: [link](http://imgur.com/DTGapli)
It seems that a relatively large proportion of the prime have $F_p\sim p/2$.

Comment: @LiamBaker Since $F_p$ divides $p-1$ it would be more interesting to plot $(p-1)/F_p=\operatorname{lcm}(k\mid q \text{ prime divides } p-1, q=a^k)$ I think.  Then many primes would give $2$ because presumably all prime factors of $p-1$ are at most squares (and not cubes etc).