# The divisors of $p-1$ and high-degree residues modulo $p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Here is a somewhat more explicit version of [a question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186766/is-rm-lcm-rm-ord-pq-colon-q-mid-p-1-q2-sqrt-p) that I asked a while ago.

> Suppose that $p$ is a prime of the form $p=2n(n+1)+1$, with a positive integer $n$. Can every odd prime divisor of $p-1$ be a residue of degree $2(n+1)$ modulo $p$? That is, can one have $q^n\equiv 1\pmod p$ for every odd prime $q\mid p-1$?

Heuristically, this is extremely unlikely, and a computer search yields no such primes in the range $1<n\le10^7$ (the case $n=1$ being a trivial exception). However, I got stuck trying to prove anything rigorously.

My guess is that this may be related to higher reciprocity laws, but at least the [Eisenstein reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_reciprocity) does not seem to help.

Comment: I agree that heuristically it's extremely unlikely. Do you have any reason to believe that a nice algebraic proof exists?

Comment: Greg: No such reasons - but I'd be equally happy with a not-so-nice proof!